# Get URL parts in Thymeleaf

Tags: url, uri, thymeleaf

I need to get some parts of the **current** URL.
I've URI addresses like:

```
/
/about
/users/john
/users/doe
```

I'm searching a way to get the string `/users` from Thymeleaf.

This `${#httpServletRequest.requestURI}` returns the entire URI.

Answer (score 3):

> In Thymeleaf html page

```
<a th:href="@{'/about'}">About</a>
```

> Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/about",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String about(ModelMap model) {
}
```